# How to get actionbar title from dynamically textview

Tags: android, textview, android-actionbar, title

I have an app which contain 2 main activities .. the first contains "Subjects" and the second contains "Categories" and both get their info from local sql database

when you choose one of subjects - from activity 1 - you will find at the top a textview which get the subject name from the database automatically

Now this textview doesn't have a fixed value but it changed according to the subject you choose

How to get the string from this textview and put in the title of the action bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep text in separate variable/list in class level to access it later.

Comment: thx but i am still new at this .. can you provide code simple ?